# Content Binding only works for integers and Strings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am very new to XAML and have to work on an existing project for university. Unfortunately I am very confused how to deal exactly with content binding.
I have the following XAML code (snippet):

```
<!-- SnapshotsV.xaml -->
<s:ScatterView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Panel.ZIndex="2" Name="SnapshotsScatterView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SnapshotsCollection}" AllowDrop="False" Background="#FF151515" Width="{Binding ScrollContainerWidth}">
    <s:ScatterView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="s:ScatterViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="300"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"/>
            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="CanScale" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="CanMove" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="CanRotate" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Center" Value="{Binding Path=ItemPosition}" />
        </Style>
    </s:ScatterView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <s:ScatterView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>

                <Label Content="{Binding Path=ID}" />
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=SnapshotImage}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </s:ScatterView.ItemTemplate>
</s:ScatterView>
```

The following View-Model belongs to this view (snippet):

```
// SnapshotsVm.cs
public class SnapshotsVm : ViewModelBase
{

   [...]

    public ObservableCollection<SnapshotItem> SnapshotsCollection
    {
        get { return SnapshotMaker.SnapshotItemCollection; }
    }
}
```

SnapshotsItemCollection is a List having one or multiple SnapshotItem-Classes. It is implemented as `ObservableCollection<SnapshotItem>`. The SnapshotItem-Class looks like the following:

```
public class SnapshotItem : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _Id;
    private Image _Image;
    private String _XMLString;
    private Point _position;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _Id; }
    }

    public String Test { get { return "abc"; } }

    public Image SnapshotImage
    {
        get { return _Image; }
    }

    public String XMLString
    {
        get { return _XMLString; }
    }

    public Point ItemPosition
    {
        get { return _position; }
    }

    public SnapshotItem(int id, String SnapshotDirectory)
    {
        this._Id = id;
        this._Image = Image.FromFile(SnapshotDirectory + @"\snapshot-" + id + @".png");
        this._XMLString = null; //TODO later
        this._position = new Point(id*400+200, 200);
    }
}
```

So far so good.

What I do not understand is the fact, that the Content Binding only works for some datatypes. As you can see in the SnapshotItem class, there is an Integer called ID and a String called Test. They work fine in XAML when I bind them via {Binding Path=ID} or {Binding Path=Test}. The other data Properties such as SnapshotImage or ItemPosition are not working.

I inspected the Variables in the SnapshotItem Class via Breakpoints. They are successfully and correctly set in the constructor. But I do not understand why I cannot use them for my Content Binding.

Additionally I have noticed that it works when I create the SnapshotItems directly in the SnapshotsVm.cs file. I created a similar class there, filled it up with random data and it worked fine. But for code logic reasons I want to create the SnapshotItems in the static SnapshotMaker class. The creation of the elements work fine and I can see them in the GUI. But the ItemPosition and the SnapshotImage cannot be bound.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What are you expecting to see when you are binding the `ItemPosition`, or `SnapshotImage` to your Label's `Content`?

Comment: When binding the ItemPosition, I expect that the ScatterView does not appear on a random place (as it does now) but on the position I specified by using this Point. And when I bind the SnapshotImage I expect to see the Image which I have loaded before in the SnapshotItem Class

Answer (score 0):

Binding of your `ScatterView` (i.e. `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SnapshotsCollection}"`) happens when you set `SnapshotsCollection` for the first time. Therefore you need to initialize all your data (e.g. positions, images, etc) when you're creating your collection.  It should look like this:

```
SnapshotsCollection = new ObservableCollection<SnapshotItem>();

int Id = 1;
var point = new Point(800,200);
var image = Image.FromFile(SnapshotDirectory + @"\snapshot-" + id + @".png");
SnapshotsCollection.Add(SnapshotMaker.Create(1, point, image));
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution by myself. I made a couple of mistakes.

Image Source={Binding Path=SnapshotImage} takes a string where the image is located. It is not possible in this way to pass the image as itself. I should read the docs more carefully.

The more tricky way was the not working Point. I did not recognized that I used the Point from the import System.Drawing.Point. It works when I use System.Windows.Point instead.

When applying both changes, everything works as intended.